# Boostrap carousel slide transition issues

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap's Carousel in a lot of my projects, works great but lately it caught my eye that the transition is weird.

What I mean with that is that when I press next or previous, either the slide displayed hides directly and the new one slides in, or the current slide slides out and the new one pops up.
What I mean is that the slides don't slide in or out all the time, [try it out](http://www.boriskamp.nl)
I need the new slide to slide in with the image visible already and the current one to slide out.

any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the issue. It's in your style.css file. If you remove the `position:relative` from this selector that should solve your problem.

```
.carousel .carousel-inner .item,.carousel .carousel-inner .active {
    height: 100%;
    /* position:relative */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pete! That did it!